# one query inside another MongoDB hangs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get only get Notes [from the notes collection] that come from meetings [from the meetings collection] that don't contain the word 'test' in them:

```
function getNotes(done) {
  noteSchema.find({}).exec((err, notes) => {
    var numNotes = 0;
    async.each(notes, (n, next) => {
                userSchema.findById(n.userId, (err, user) => {
                if (err || !user) { next(); return; }
                var emailsStr = utils.getEmailsString(user.emails);
                if (!utils.toSkipEmail(emailsStr)) {
                    meetingSchema.findById(n.meetingId, (err, meeting)  => {
                    if (err || !meeting) { next(); return; }
                        if (meeting.name.displayValue.indexOf('test', 'Test') == -1) {
                            numNotes++;
                }
              next();
              });
            }
          })
    }, (err, result) => {
      console.log(util.format('Total Number of Notes: %d', numNotes));
      done(null);
    });
  });
}
```

The code works fine without adding in the lines to find the meetings by ID. It hangs at that point.

For reference, here is the start of a function that comes later to filter out any 'test' or 'Test' containing meetings.

```
function getMeetings(done) {
  meetingSchema.find({
    'name.displayValue': { '$regex' : '(?!.*test)^.*$' , '$options' : 'i' }
  }).exec((err, meetings) => {
```

Relevant lines of Notes Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var noteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    meetingId: {type: String, default: ''},
});

exports.Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);
```

The meeting schema has no notes field.

Comment: can you show the schema defs please?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I were going to go after a solution like this, where I wanted to get all notes that weren't part of a meeting w/ the word 'test' in the name, I'd probably go the other way with it, unless there's a whole ton of notes you could just get all notes and populate them with their meetings, and then do the filtering.  assuming your NoteSchema defines something like:

```
meeting : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Meeting'}
```

then in your query you could do (given the notATest function that returns true or false appropriately:

```
Note.find({}).populate('meeting').exec((e, n) => {
  _.omit(n, (note) => { return notATest(note.meeting.name); });
});
```

Alternatively, you could search for all meetings that are not a test first, and call `.populate('notes')` on them, if the 'ref' goes the other way.

Comment: I would like to try the first technique. The reason being, my note and meetings schemas include no references to one another and it makes more sense for me to have a note reference its meeting instead of vice versa... though, that may be more computationally intensive. If you could show me how to do it either way, I would really appreciate it.

The schemas use Mongoose. I will add them to my original question now.